# Square free elements in the value set of a polynomial

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

At the end of this [this article (conjecture 7.2)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.14711), the author proposes (with some justification) a conjecture a bit more general than the following one: if $P$ is a non constant and separable polynomial, whose coefficients belong to a principal ideal domain, and if the gcd of the values of $P$ is 1, then there are infinitely many square-free elements in the value set of $P$.
This conjecture is (allegedly) proved in the course of the article whenever the domain contains finitely many prime elements.

If we restrict it to $\mathbb Z$, then it suffices to prove that $P(x)$ is square-free for at least one $x > 0$.

I would be surprised if someone has not conjectured the same elsewhere, perhaps even proved it. What do you think about that?

Comment: This is open for irreducible polynomials of degree 4 or higher. An equivalent conjecture, and many references, may be found in the introduction to a paper of Poonen: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-118/issue-2/Squarefree-values-of-multivariable-polynomials/10.1215/S0012-7094-03-11826-8.short